# WPF Canvas will not draw correctly in loop

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I'm currently working on a tiled map editor with WPF using canvas for drawing, but for some reason it's not working with a loop.

I've generated a 160px160p map basing on 16x16 tiles. 
When I try to add them in a loop it doesn't add them.

```
    public void DrawFullMap()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < cMap.mapFile.lMap.Count; i++ )
        {
            MapPoint mp = cMap.mapFile.lMap[i];
            pWindow.DrawOnCanvas(mp.x, mp.y, tileWidth, tileHeight, mp.iTileID);
        }
    }

        private void DrawOnCanvas(int x, int y, int tileWidth, int tileHeight, int index)
        {
            if (editor != null)
            {
                Image imgAdd = new Image();
                imgAdd.Source = editor.Tileset[index];
                imgAdd.Width = tileWidth;
                imgAdd.Height = tileHeight;
                imgAdd.Margin = new Thickness(x * tileWidth, y * tileHeight, 0, 0);
                cvMap.Children.Add(imgAdd);
                // Textbox for debug
                tbdbg.Text += "X: " + x + " Y:" + y + " Tile:" + index + "\n";
            }
       }
```

On use, the textbox I've created should contain all the tiles I want to add, and it does, but for some reason the canvas remains empty (or only adds 1-4 tiles, depends on the canvas size). [click for example](http://i.epvpimg.com/WxPQf.png)

When trying to add them manually (MouseEvent) it's working fine, only the loop is causing issues.
Why?

**EDIT:** 
Changed the margin to SetTop & SetLeft, adding the function for generating the map

```
        private void DrawOnCanvas(int x, int y, int tileWidth, int tileHeight, int index)
        {
            if (editor != null)
            {
                Image imgAdd = new Image()
                {
                    Width = tileWidth,
                    Height = tileHeight,
                    Source = editor.Tileset[index],
                };
                Canvas.SetTop(imgAdd, y * tileHeight);
                Canvas.SetLeft(imgAdd, x * tileWidth);
                cvMap.Children.Add(imgAdd);
                // Textbox for debug
                tbdbg.Text += "X: " + x + " Y:" + y + " Tile:" + index + "\n";
            }
       }

    public void CreateMapfile(int width, int height)
    {
        mapFile = new Map();
        mapFile.iWidth = width;
        mapFile.iHeight = height;
        mapFile.lMap = new List<MapPoint>();
        for(int i = 0; i < height; i+=16)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < width; j+=16)
            {
                MapPoint mp = new MapPoint();
                mp.x = i;
                mp.y = j;
                mp.eType = TileType.Normal;
                mp.iLayer = 0;
                mp.iTileID = 0;
                this.mapFile.lMap.Add(mp);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Found the problem**

Alright, that was an issue on my side. 
Since I used

```
Canvas.SetTop(imgAdd, y * tileHeight);
```

I forgot that the values I previously used were the tile position, not the width.
When setting a tile manually, it showed, as example, X: 1 Y: 2, whereas the loop showed X: 16 Y: 32. Seems like I'm missing my coffee today, haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldnt be using margin to place items on a Canvas. You have to set position of the images using Canvas.SetTop and Canvas.SetLeft. I am guessing that all your images are added to the canvas but at the same location so that you only see one object at any given time.

See more about adding controls to canvas on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I changed it using SetTop & SetLeft but unfortunately the issue still remains. Thanks for the tip with margin & SetTop/SetLeft, I didn't bother with it since margin worked properly.

Comment: In the image you have provided (I am guess is the log file), you have x and y values to be 0?? is that right? and index is always 0? Can you post the new code where you set top and left of the image please?

Comment: The tile remains the same (thought about using a different one for each tile but the result was the same), x & y are being generated by a class. I added the new function & the function for generating the map to the main post

Comment: I think your placement of images is wrong. Can you change this line Canvas.SetTop(imgAdd, y * tileHeight); to Canvas.SetTop(imgAdd, y); and similarly to the SetLeft as well and try again?

Comment: In the end that was the problem. I noticed it after trying to add one manually and checking the X & Y variables, they showed the position in the grid (x & y / 16) instead of the correct x & y values. Thank you very much. :)